# Are there any theory about data clustering that relate to this intuition?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Are there any theories or online papers about data clustering (with any clustering technique and data generated by any model) that relate to this intuition?

When the model parameters (including number of clusters k) are predetermined, the more the data points, the more accurate the data points can be accurately assigned to its respective true clusters using a certain clustering technique, or the posterior clustering results of the points more accurately match the true clusters they belong to.

Comment: If you assume that you clusters are generated by a simple Gaussian process, this will probably hold. On real data: no, life isn't this simple.

Comment: In particular there is no such thing as "true cluster", clustering is not about truth and lie, but rather about infinite number of possible structures to extract